# Pentaho Data Integration appends bin/javaw.exe to already existing string

Tags: java, pentaho

When I execute spoon, I get the following:

```
C:\pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386\data-integration>spoon
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe\bin\javaw.exe
```

I've added an environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\(x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73
```

I verified my PATH environment variable which looks like this. (showing only the java path):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin
```

No matter what I try I get the wrong path with a double bin\javaw.exe

How can I get spoon to use the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME should be the home folder of java: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\" and not the location of the binary java.exe.

Comment: I know. The question is where does _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME gets its value from.

In the end, I removed JAVA_HOME which didn't do anything better or worse. I installed a later version of java, then logged out and back in. At this point I have my _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME showing only javaw.exe and it works somehow...